# polar plot using javafx charts

Tags: javafx, polar-coordinates

I am creating a polar plot (star plot) and would like to do it in JavaFX.  I have seen a couple of commercial companies that have this ability, however, I would like to have a homegrown library that we can modify later as necessary.  I have researched the documentation and libraries to find a way to create a polar plot.  I am not having any luck.  Can you point me in the right direction please? I looked at the CategoryAxis, NumberAxis, ValueAxis, ScatterChart, PieChart, LineChart with no avail.  It's mainly the circular grid that I'm looking at and having issues with, not even the plotted data.  I have worked with the Arc and Canvas, along with the Scenegraph with Arcs.  I would really like to use the chart features such as plotting data and linking that data to a table on a polar plot. My initial thought was to use the XY Chart with the radius as one axis and the angles that the Axis points would be at.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Another question, should I use a canvas to draw the polar plot or use nodes if I don't use the charting capability in javafx?  This is a think client.

Answer (score 2):

*On implementing a PolarChart natively in JavaFX*

I think you will need to subclass [Chart](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/Chart.html) directly (to create a new chart type - PolarChart) rather than use [XYChart](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.html).

You can borrow heavily from the [XYChart implementation](https://bitbucket.org/openjfxmirrors/openjfx-8-master-rt/src/4faca009f76bb8b33ab8244e710c9d471cb57b1e/modules/controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.java) (and possibly even the [PieChart implementation](https://bitbucket.org/openjfxmirrors/openjfx-8-master-rt/src/4faca009f76bb8b33ab8244e710c9d471cb57b1e/modules/controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/chart/PieChart.java?at=default) when creating your new PolarChart.  There is existing Java code for PolarCharts in JavaFX, that you could help which (though it uses a different framework and rendering technology) some of the may provide some inspiration when creating your PolarChart, see for instance: [DefaultPolarItemRender.java](http://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/source/org/jfree/chart/renderer/DefaultPolarItemRenderer.java) and [PolarPlot.java](http://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/source/org/jfree/chart/plot/PolarPlot.java).

My guess is that implementation will be challenging and a significant amount of work.

*On using Alternate Technology*

Alternatively, you could use Java 8 and embed a JFreeChart polar plot in a JavaFX application using a [SwingNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/embed_swing/jfxpub-embed_swing.htm) or use one of the many excellent JavaScript based plotting libraries (such as [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar)), by embedding the JavaScript rendered chart in a [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm).

Comment: What existing java code is in the PolarCharts of JavaFX?  I think I missed that when researching.  I have looked at JFreeChart and some others, but since I'm required to stay at Java 7 for now, I'm not able to incorporate swing into the application.

Comment: There is currently no existing code for polar charts in JavaFX.  If you want to use JavaFX to plot such a chart, you will need to derive from Chart and write the code yourself.

Comment: For anyone that wants to use **JFreeChart** in JavaFX, it's not necessary to use `SwingNode` as there is a canvas-based `ChartViewer` node built into JFreeChart.

Comment: Though JFreeChart does have ChartViewer JavaFX as replacement for ChartPanel Swing, it does not seem to support CSS styling of the PolarPlot. Both JFreeChart class and PolarPlot class still uses some Java Swing/AWT code.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of rewriting the logic of polar plots in JavaFx, you might want to reuse some already existing JavaScript library. I wrote a wrapper for using the famous JavaScript library d3.js from within JavaFx:

https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/javafx-d3

It allows you to utilize the power of d3 to create beautiful graphics and plots in JavaFx. Here is an example for a d3.js polar plot:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4583749

```
var data = d3.range(0, 2 * Math.PI, .01).map(function(t) {
  return [t, Math.sin(2 * t) * Math.cos(2 * t)];
});

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - 30;

var r = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, .5])
    .range([0, radius]);

var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
    .radius(function(d) { return r(d[1]); })
    .angle(function(d) { return -d[0] + Math.PI / 2; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var gr = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "r axis")
  .selectAll("g")
    .data(r.ticks(5).slice(1))
  .enter().append("g");

gr.append("circle")
    .attr("r", r);

gr.append("text")
    .attr("y", function(d) { return -r(d) - 4; })
    .attr("transform", "rotate(15)")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

var ga = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "a axis")
  .selectAll("g")
    .data(d3.range(0, 360, 30))
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + -d + ")"; });

ga.append("line")
    .attr("x2", radius);

ga.append("text")
    .attr("x", radius + 6)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d < 270 && d > 90 ? "end" : null; })
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return d < 270 && d > 90 ? "rotate(180 " + (radius + 6) + ",0)" : null; })
    .text(function(d) { return d + "°"; });

svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
```

You can apply the strategy of javafx-d3 to include any JavaScript library you want. The following polar blot library is build on top of d3.js and might provide some more specialized functionality:

https://github.com/biovisualize/micropolar